# Moving table row td data up and down except first td of that row to re-order data

Tags: javascript, jquery

I've been trying to get this working so that the first td of a row, the position, will not move whilst the user is moving the other data in that row up or down.

jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/qjd8w/6/

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.up, .down').click(function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        var row = $(this).parents("tr:first").children().not(':first'); 
        //causes error

        if ($(this).is(".up")) {
            row.insertBefore(row.prev());
        } 
        else {
            row.insertAfter(row.next());
        }
    });
});
```

var row = $(this).parents("tr:first") -- on its own has the desired effect, but that moves the position up and down along with the rest of the row.

I don't want the position to move at all, so it will always stay in order(1, 2, 3, 4)

Any help at all is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One option would be to simply renumber the first column:

http://jsfiddle.net/FWCJm/

```
$('tbody tr td:first-child').each(function(idx, item) {
    $(this).text(idx+1);
});
```